# Отключить прокрутку карты при клике на метку

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты

Если кликнуть по метке, которая стоит близко к краю карты, то открывшийся балун прокрутит карту так, чтобы стать видным полностью.

Можно ли отключить такое поведение на Ymaps API 2.1?

Мне нужно, чтобы балун открылся, но карта осталась на месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть опция autoPan https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/#Balloon__param-options.autoPan 
Для метки например будет выглядеть так:

```
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.907228, 31.260503], {},{
        balloonAutoPan: false
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1yj23hwv/